# How do I iterate through a file containing a list of floating point numbers in Python?

Tags: python, file

I need to write a program that reads a file containing a list of floating-point numbers and counts how many of those numbers are larger than a user-specified threshold.

numbers.txt -

- 5.0
- 15.0
- 25.0

This is my python code -

```
in_file = open("numbers.txt", "r")
number = float(in_file.read())  # error in python
user_input = float(input("Threshold: "))
if number > user_input:
    print(number)
in_file.close()
```

Python is unable to convert the string to a float because the numbers have a new line after each number and python is trying to convert that into a float. I tried to change line 2 in my code to add a strip method but it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: stackoverflow is not codewriting service. Atleast you should post what have you tried. And there are many examples how to read a numbers from file

Comment: you are trying to convert entire file to `float`. You should convert each line to float

Comment: Sorry I was having issues posting my question. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open("numbers.txt", "r"):
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    num = float(line)
```

im sure you can continue from here..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as fp:
    lst = [float(line.strip()) for line in fp if line.strip()]
    user_input = float(input("Threshold: "))
    for num in lst:
        if num > user_input:
            print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround

```
inputdata = []
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        try:
            number = float(row)
            inputdata.append(number)
        except:
            pass
```